# Multiple element drag, resize, rotate and delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to create a simple "let's build a look" tool which basically allows a user to drag a div (with an image inside) on to a target area, resize it, rotate it or delete it and do the same with several other elements.

I can create the drag part to all elements and also resize one element but can't do it do more than one.

Here's what I have (I have copied partially the code from an example found here in Stackoverflow):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      //Counter
      counts = [0];

      $(".closeMe").hide();

      $(".dragImg").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        containment: "#droppable",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move",
        start: function(event, ui) {
                counts[0]++;
                isDraggingMedia = true;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            isDraggingMedia = false;
        }
      });

      $("#droppable").droppable({
        accept: ".dragImg",
        drop: function(e, ui){
            if(ui.draggable.hasClass("dragImg"))
                 $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
            //Pointing to the dragImg class in dropHere and add new class.
            $("#droppable .dragImg").addClass("item-"+counts[0]);
            //Remove the current class (ui-draggable and dragImg)
            $("#droppable .item-"+counts[0]).removeClass("dragImg ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging");       

            $("#droppable .item-"+counts[0]+" .closeMe").addClass("del-"+counts[0]);


            $(".item-"+counts[0]).click(function(){
                $(".item-"+counts[0]+" .closeMe").show();
                //$(".item-"+counts[0]).attr('class', 'ui-draggable-helper');
                $(".item-"+counts[0]+" img").resizable({
                    aspectRatio: true
                });

            });   

            make_draggable($(".item-"+counts[0]));              
        }
      });

      var zIndex = 0;
      function make_draggable(elements){   
            elements.draggable({
                containment:'#droppable',
                start:function(e,ui){ ui.helper.css('z-index',++zIndex); },
                stop:function(e,ui){}
            });
      }

  });
```

What I can not do is to achieve resize to every element or even have found a decent way to rotate them or delete them.

I want to click to select and show handles that allow resize, rotate and select and also when clicking outside the element, the handles should disappear.

How can i do this ?

Comment: can you please a fiddle of your code and paste the link in your question...

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to answer the question accurately since the HTML is not provided, but I created a tiny sample page implementing these functionalities (dragging, dropping, deleting and resizing). Deleting uses the droppable 'trash' div, you may want to implement the delete functionality within the element similar to drag and resize.

Since jQuery UI provides no rotating functionality in itself, I left that one out. There is several plugins offering this kind of functionality so you should decide which suits you best. Rotating is also offere in CSS3, but you should keep in mind that this approach is very likely to have some browser compatibility issues, for more information see http://caniuse.com/transforms2d.

EDIT: Added a link to a very minimalistic demo application with this functionality: https://github.com/relicode/dragdrop-minimalistic/

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>jQuery draggable / droppable test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <style>

        .drop-hover {
            border: solid green 3px;
        }

        .handle {
            display: none;
        }

        .move-handle {
            cursor: move;
        }

        .rotate-handle {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .resize-handle {
            cursor: nwse-resize;
        }

        .trash {
            background-color: silver;
            display: table-cell;
            height: 100px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 100px;
        }

        div.area {
            border: solid black 1px;
            float: left;
            height: 500px;
            width: 300px;
        }

        div.interactable {
            background-color: silver;
            height: 100px;
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
        }

        div.interactable-tools {
            bottom: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }

        p {
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id='target-area' class='area'>
        <p>target</p>
        <div class='trash' id='trash'>Trash</div>
    </div>
    <div id='source-area' class='area'>
        <p>source</p>
        <div class='interactable'>
            Draggable 1
            <div class='interactable-tools'>
                <span class='handle move-handle'>Mo</span>
                <span class='handle rotate-handle'>Ro</span>
                <!-- <span class='handle resize-handle'>Re</span> -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='interactable'>
            Draggable 2
            <div class='interactable-tools'>
                <span class='handle move-handle'>Mo</span>
                <span class='handle rotate-handle'>Ro</span>
                <!-- <span class='handle resize-handle'>Re</span> -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='interactable'>
            Draggable 3
            <div class='interactable-tools'>
                <span class='handle move-handle'>Mo</span>
                <span class='handle rotate-handle'>Ro</span>
                <!-- <span class='handle resize-handle'>Re</span> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var counts = 0; // make sure you use var before your variable name to prevent declaring it as a global variable

            $('.interactable')
                .resizable()
                .draggable({
                    handle: '.move-handle'
                })
                .hover(function() {
                    $(this).find('.handle').toggle();
                }, function() {
                    $(this).find('.handle').toggle();
                });
            ;

            $('#target-area').droppable({
                drop: function(ev) {
                    counts += 1;
                }
            });

            $('#trash').droppable({
                accept: '.interactable',
                drop: function(ev) {
                    $(ev.toElement).parent().parent().remove();
                },
                hoverClass: 'drop-hover'
            });

        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want the elements to be resizable nor rotatable before being clicked on after they have been dropped. Imagine as if you were creating a landscape and you drag trees and flowers from a sidebar list. Only after they have been dropped into the main div they can be resized or rotated after being clicked upon.